# Is this an 'easy to understand' data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures

Here is a data structure for List of items where each list contains
a List of 4 Strings, each list of 4 items contains a List of 5 Strings :

```
List<List<List<String>>> l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
```

Is there a more 'readable' way to define this data structure ?

A jsp file is expecting a structure of this kind to display the data.

Comment: It is not easy to understand

Comment: that's what comments are for.

Comment: Your description of the structure doesn't seem reflected in the structure specified.

Comment: I have bad news, you should rather write it `List<List<List<String>>> l`, not `List l`, so actually idiomatic code will be longer, not shorter.

Comment: Why would you ever want to use something like that?

Comment: I really don't see the difference between `List<String>` and `new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>()`

Comment: Can you describe what you are planning to do with that monster?

Comment: This is not the code you are searching for - Obi-Wan

Comment: If you want to scare the programmer who will repair your code, this is a good way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using classes, to give a *meaningful name* to the things, instead of a "list of lists of lists of strings", which is *not* at all meaningful.

Instead of describing the *technical* aspects, the type names should also describe the *meaning*.

Whenever you end up writing code that looks like this, you need to start doing OOP!

Because sooner or later you will be *using* the data structure with spaghetti code like this:

```
 if (a.get(0).get(0).get(0).equals("banana")) {
```

AAArgh. Bad code alert! Start *naming classes* and adding methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

```
List<List<List<String>>> l = new ArrayList<>();
```

(for java 1.7 or later)

Comment: It's a more readable *constructor*, but the data structure remains just as unreadable as before.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse BTW, author asked about *constructor* structure :)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that. But that doesn't make this the right thing to do. ;-) Plus, it's still empty - adding a `String` to this structure is still a huge mess. But the -1 you got was IMHO not fair, I gave you a +1 for giving a straight drop-in code.

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that if you really need this structure for some horrible reason, make OOP model with classes, and make a converter to `List<List<List<String>>>`
I am sure it is a lot easier to understand what are you doing, maintain it later, if you don't just throw there a 3 dimension list of strings with some mysterious logic. I guarantee if you look back the code a year later you won't remember all the reason how did you fill up the structure, and I wouldn't be happy if I get a 3rd party program which uses this structure.